# Examples of Gorenstein algebras

Tags: rt.representation-theory

What are classes of finite dimensional Gorenstein algebras in the literature, which are not selfinjective and have infinite global dimension? 
While it is not hard to construct specific examples of such algebras, no big class comes to my mind having this property.

Comment: [Here](https://www.math.uni-bielefeld.de/~sek/sem/abs/zhangpu4.pdf) are examples in section $3$; I suppose one can generalise them. Of course, what "big class" means, is open to discussion.